# Export table dump using SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I need export table dump using SQL DEVELOPER

I do: `View->DBA` then right click on `data pump` and then  `data pump export wizard`

In opened `export wizard` window, I choose `Tables` type, then click next and  in second step, there are not displayed any tables: [image]
Though, I have several tables in current connection (under this user).

What is problem here? why I cant see table list for exporting?

SQL DEVELOPER version: 4.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the 'Lookup' button.

By default it will export all tables for your user. Use this page if you only want to export certain tales.

Click the 'More' button if you want to browse by user.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I've been tempted to make that wizard state explicitly that everything is included unless specifically added on this page...