# Oracle table filter

Tags: oracle, filter, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an unknown database to analyze. For this I imported a DMP file with the user system (I also took the password from the export batch). With SQL Developer I can access the database. In the case of tables, however, "filtered" is shown. After all tables have been exported, the expected data is not in the SQL file.

I think I have to turn off the filter on the tables, but I don't know how to do that. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: What?  Do not understand

Comment: Hard to understand what is your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975518/export-table-dump-using-sql-developer may guide you somehow

Comment: Why would anything be in a sql file unless you put it there?

Answer (score 0):

The *filter* is, I believe, to exclude recycle bin objects.

Check it by

- right-clicking the "Tables (Filtered)"
- choose "Apply Filter" to see which one is enabled
- if you don't want it, choose "Clear Filter"